# iOS get wrong frame after set autolayout use snapkit

Tags: ios, swift

I add a UIView in `UIStoryboard` and bind it to a custom UIView class called testView,next, I create a UIView called subView in textView in `require init` function ,

**this is my step**

1 initialization the subView

2 add new subView to textView

3 set autolayout

4 set cornerRadius (view.frame.height / 2)

After run the app  the cornerRadius does not change

then I try to print the frame of subView , it get (0,0,0,0)

this is my code

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
   super.init(coder: aDecoder)

   circelView = UIView()
   self.addSubview(circelView)
   circelView.snp_makeConstraints(closure: { (make) -> Void in
       make.size.equalTo(80)
       make.top.equalTo(self.snp_top)
       make.right.equalTo(self.snp_right)
   })
   print(circelView.frame) //get wrong frame
   circelView.layer.cornerRadius = circelView.frame.size.height / 2
   circelView.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

Comment: you should be able to force `self.layoutSubviews()` and then you should get the frame you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your view hasn't had time to be laid out by the time you print the frame and set the corner radius. Adding an AutoLayout constraint doesn't automatically layout the view.

To get the correct result, you need to set your corner radius after the view has been laid out. This will guarantee that you have a frame that is constrained by your AutoLayout constraints.

To do so, place any code that requires the correct frame in 'viewDidLayoutSubviews':

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    print(circelView.frame) // The frame will have been set
    circelView.layer.cornerRadius = circelView.frame.size.height / 2
}
```

`viewDidLayoutSubviews()` is a method on `UIViewController` that you can override, check out the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLayoutSubviews).